# android, imageviews inside linear layout don't fit the screen size

Tags: android, layout, fullscreen

I was wondering how to make the four images inside my LinearLayout look as big as possible depending on the screen. When I install the widget in my phone, it always fits only 50% of the screen.
Here comes the xml.
Any hints?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|clip_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/hora1_current"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/neutro_on" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/hora2_current"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/neutro_on" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/minuto1_current"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/neutro_on" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/minuto2_current"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/neutro_on" />
```

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Should it be android:layout_width="fill_parent"????

Comment: You want your images to fill the screen's width?

Comment: Yes, I want them to fill the screen.

Comment: Regarding the width="wrap_content" instead the obvious "fill_parent": if I do this, then I only get the first image in the screen, the rest are gone.

Comment: How do you want them stacked?

Comment: I'm doing a clock Widget and I'm replacing every number with an image, so they must be placed like 1514 where everynumber is represented by it's corresponding image.

Comment: The problem was at the appwidgetProviderInfo object, it doesn't matter what is set in the layout/main, the aspect of the widget is defined here and wont be override for the main layout xml.
Thanks everybody for your valious help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:weightSum="1"` to your parent linear layout.
The linear layout should have `android:orientation="horizontal"`
Now to each of your image views , add `android:layout_weight = 0.25`.

Hope this works.

Comment: i forgot to add ... in your image views mention android:layout_width = "0dip"

Answer (score 0):

hope you read enough about orientation vertical and horizontal .

you should clear here that by filling screen whether you mean altogether all 4 fills the screen such that each takes 25% or every one should take 100% width and added up vertically .

1. for first case add `android:layout_weight=1` for every imageView .
2. for second case replace `android:orientation="horizontal"` by `android:orientation="vertical"` in root LinerLayout

Comment: First case is what I'm looking for. Gonna try it, thanks in advance.

Comment: After applying layout_weight=1 the widget still fills only 50% of the screen :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't use wrap content, instead use the actual dimensions of the image or fill parent.